# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I have the following markup (Note its being rendered via a php eval function):

```
 <div class="my-gallery">
      ...
 </div>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>

   $.getScript("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js")
         .done(function() {

              $('.my-gallery').magnificPopup({
                  type: 'image',
                  gallery: {
                     enabled: true
                  }
             }); 

        })
       .fail(function() {
            console.log('fail');
       });

 </script>
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function
```

*** UPDATE ***

When change the code to following it work:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

 <script>

       $('.my-gallery').magnificPopup({
                  type: 'image',
                  gallery: {
                     enabled: true
                  }
       }); 

 </script>
```

This is very strange. Why does it not work when using the `$.getScript()` method.
In the network tab it looks like its making a call twice see image:

[image: network tab]

Comment: I can't reproduce it: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/bc4f6k9h/1/. Is there any chance you loaded multiple copies of jQuery? That often causes errors like this.

Comment: @Barmar there is only one copy of jQuery. This is very strange some very odd behaviour is happening.

Comment: What does `typeof $(".my-gallery").magnificPopup` print?

Comment: @Barmar sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Type that in the JavaScript console. The error says it's not a function, it would be helpful to see if it's some other type of value.

Comment: @Barmer I get `undefined`

Comment: Are you sure `$.getScript()` isn't getting an error? If you look in the Sources tab, do you see the script URL loaded?

Comment: @Barmar in the sources tab I can see both jquery and magnificpopup. Very strange.

Comment: Very strange indeed. Do you use `$.noConflict` anywhere?

Comment: @Barmar in the network tab I can see its making a call to get the magnificscript twice - see my screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. I thought there was a problem that the download is only 7KB instead of 20KB, but that's the correct gzip'ed size.

Comment: @Barmar I've changed the url to include `https://` which now prevents the redirects But I'm still getting `undefined` in the console.

Comment: @Barmar note the above code is being called a via a php eval function. Could that be the issue?

Comment: How can a PHP eval function call JavaScript? PHP runs on the server, JS runs on the client. You'll need to update the code in the question to show what you're talking about.

Answer (score -1):

In my case Kaspersky Internet Security function antibaner blocked normal operation. Try disabling your antivirus.